# Using tor with palemoon is possible or not

Tags: chat

I just want to use tor with palemoon and want to know if its possible or not. I need tor because i can refresh the ips and needs works with imacros a program that repeat tasks. But how i can do so tor will work with palemoon and imacros. some trick or solution to this

Answer (score 0):

On Linux:
Install the tor application, and enable and start the service. In Palemoon, go to the Tools -> Settings -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings. Choose Manual Proxy configuration. Socks Host: 127.0.0.1 Port 9050. Check: Use Proxy to perform DNS Queries

On Windows:
Start the Tor Browser to start the Tor Proxy. In Palemoon, go to the Tools -> Settings -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings. Choose Manual Proxy configuration.
Socks Host: 127.0.0.1 Port 9150. Check: Use Proxy to perform DNS Queries